# Images are not loaded into PDF using VB6 with mjwPDF class

Tags: pdf, vb6, pdf-generation

I am using a `VB6` class named `mjwPDF.cls` and trying to parse some images into `PDF` document.
However it doesn't display the images and Adobe gives "pdf broken" messages.

Here what I've done (basicly):

```
Dim objPDF As mjwPDF

Private Sub blabla()
    Set objPDF = New mjwPDF
    With objPDF
        .PDFTitle = "My PDF Document"
        .PDFFileName = 'MyFileFullPath
        .PDFLoadAfm = App.Path & "\Fonts"
        .PDFSetLayoutMode = LAYOUT_DEFAULT
        .PDFFormatPage = FORMAT_A4
        .PDFOrientation = ORIENT_PORTRAIT
        .PDFSetUnit = UNIT_PT
        .PDFView = False
        .PDFBeginDoc
        .PDFSetFont FONT_TIMES, 5, FONT_NORMAL
        .PDFSetTextColor = vbBlack
        .PDFUseOutlines = True
        .PDFTextOut "Something bla bla bla.."
        .PDFImage 'MyImageFullPath.jpg, x + 15, y + 15, 100, 100
        .PDFTextOut "Something bla bla bla.."
        .PDFEndPage
        .PDFEndDoc
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is the class: [mjwPDF.cls](http://trac.assembla.com/bNo460JIar3yLWab7jnrAJ/browser/mjwPDF.cls?rev=18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i copied your code into my project and my jpg file shows flawlessly

maybe there is a problem with your jpg file? could you attach it or try another file? i used a bmp file which i converted to jpg using ms paint

something which i couldnt test are your x and y coordinates. what are the values of the  ariables x and y? in my test i usex x=100 and y=100

Comment: Damn! I defined x,y as integer and thought that's enough for initial 0 value but it's not. So yea it's the initial value problem thank you!

Comment: and thank you for posting your code, it did help me with an error i had :)